# Implications of violating Bayesian network independence assumptions during inference

Tags: bayesian-network, graphical-model, conditional-independence

Consider the example Bayesian network below where $X \perp \!\!\! \perp Y $ (X is independent of Y).

[image: Example Bayesian network]

Assuming that this is the true independence structure of the process that is generating the data, we could for instance infer
$$
P(Z|X,Y) = \frac{ p(Z|X)p(Z|Y)P(X)P(Y)}{\sum_{Z}P(Z|X)P(Z|Y)P(X)P(Y)}.
$$

I would like to know if there is some way to **quantify the error we make when modelling a given process using an incorrect/ imperfect independence structure**.

For instance, suppose the true data distribution is described by the Bayesian network below, but that the independence structure we use for inference (our model of reality) is the (partially incorrect and simplified) graph above.

[image]

Is there a way to compute the sensitivity of our inference ability on how accurately we model the independence structure?

Perhaps computing the KL divergence between the inferred variable and the true variable could be a solution?

$$
\mathrm{independence~structure~importance } = KL(P(Z),\bar{P(Z)})
$$

Where $P(Z)$ the true/correct probability and $\bar{P(Z)}$ the estimation using incorrect independence assumptions.

Any suggestions or improvements to the terminology I used will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the formula provided be for $P(Z|X,Y)$ instead of $P(Z)$? Second, in the numerator and denominator both $p$ and $P$ have been used - do they have any special difference of meaning, or simply stand for probability? Finally, [these refutation techniques in dowhy library](https://github.com/py-why/dowhy#iv-refute-the-obtained-estimate) might have what you are looking for. I have not gone through them in detail, but the overview seems to indicate towards what you want.

Comment: Anirban, Thank you. I have corrected the question.
Thank you also for introducing me to refutation methods. This seems like a viable way to address this problem.